# Leetcode problem of add two numbers using linked lists not running on editor of leetcode

Tags: java, linked-list

I am fairly new to java(About a month) and in fact new to coding.I was going through a question on leetcode.I made a code for it and it ran perfectly fine in vscode.But on online editor of leetcode where i have to submit the answer it shows compile time error.Can anyone help?Also can anyone guide me if they see this code as too lengthy??I did this while i am studying linked lists.Below is the code...

```
public class linkedlistcreation {
    public static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;

        public  Node(int data){
            this.data=data;
            this.next=null;
        }
    }

    public static void display(Node firstnode){
        for(Node x=firstnode;x!=null;x=x.next){
            System.out.print(x.data + "=>");
        }
    }

    //method to compare their lengths.
    public static void compare(Node newfirst,Node root){
        int count =0;
        int j=0;
        Node y;
        Node x;
        for(x=newfirst;x!=null;x=x.next){
            count=count+1;
        }
        for( y=root;y!=null;y=y.next){
            j=j+1;
        }
        if(count==j){
            return;
        }
        if(count>j){
            Node last=new Node(0);
            while(j<count){
                y.next=last;
                j++;
            }
            return;
        }
        if(count<j){
            Node last=new Node(0);
            while(count<j){
                x.next=last;
                count++;
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void add(int z,Node firstnode,Node root){
        if(firstnode==null && root==null){
            return;
        }
       
        Node x=firstnode;
        Node y=root;
        x.data=z+x.data+y.data;
        if(x.data>=10){
            x.data=(x.data-10);
            if(x.next==null&& y.next==null){
                Node last=new Node(0);
                x.next=last;
                last.data=1;
                return;
            }
            add(1, x.next, y.next);
        }
        else{
            add(0, x.next, y.next);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        //first list // number passed in it is 6=>4=>3=>5=>6 so as per question we have forst operand as 65346
        Node first=new Node(4);
        Node second=new Node(3);
        Node third=new Node(5);
        Node fourth=new Node(6);
       
        first.next=second;
        second.next=third;
        third.next=fourth;

        //adding a new node at the first node.Just for checking my understanding.
        Node newfirst=new Node(6);
        newfirst.next=first;

        //second list// second operand is 84467
        Node root=new Node(7);
        Node firs=new Node(6);
        Node secon=new Node(4);
        Node thir=new Node(4);
        Node four=new Node(8);
        
        root.next=firs;
        firs.next=secon;
        secon.next=thir;
        thir.next=four;
      
        compare(newfirst,root);
       
        add(0,newfirst,root);
        display(newfirst);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the compiler runs your code it runs  **its own** main function with the line: `ListNode ret = new Solution().addTwoNumbers(param_1, param_2);` Which means that you don't have to implement the main, but a class `Solution` with a function `addTwoNumbers(param_1, param_2)`, which get the appropriate parameters and returns the appropriate object.
In [your](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) problem (right?), the function should  return `ListNode` object - which had been defined (you don't have to implemnt it), so your `Node` class is unnecessary.

You can see a detailed guide for the problem in the *Solution* tab.

Comment: 1)So i have to write Only the Function?No main function?You say that node class is unnecessary How can I create a linked list without making a node?

Comment: So you mean that I don't have to create a node.Nodes have been already created?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to implement the `main` function and the `Node` class.
You can see in the default code outside the `Solution` class, an annotated class (in your case - `ListNode`) that you should use instead of the `Node` class. 
You can see the default code using the *Reset to default code definition* button.